# Is this sentence wrong? (Comparative Adverbs)

Tags: adverbs, comparison

Question : The Spanish athlete / run / fast / than the other runners

1. The Spanish athlete **ran more fastly** than the other runners.
2. The Spanish athlete **ran faster** than the other runners.

In my comparative adverb worksheet, my tutor said that the first sentence is the correct one, while it doesn't sound right to me. Is it wrong? And if it's not, is there any difference between the first and second sentence?

Comment: Your tutor is talking nonsense. _Rans_ is not an English word, and neither is _fastly_.

Comment: Edit your phrases

Comment: If that's not a typo and your tutor really said "rans more fastly," get a new tutor.

Comment: After you've edited the 'rans' to 'ran' it's still incorrect (or at the very least very clunky). 2 is the correct answer. Get a new tutor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast is both an adverb and an adjective. The word "fastly" does not exist. With short adverbs that do not end in -ly comparative and superlative forms are identical to adjectives: add -er to form the comparative (e.g: faster, harder, later) and -est to form the superlative (e.g: fastest, hardest, latest). If the adverb ends in e, remove it before adding the ending.

This would be the right sentence:

> The Spanish athlete ran faster than the other runners.

Make sure to check out [this great article](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative-adverbs/). It has all of the answers you need.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is definitely the correct one because **rans** is not an English word and you can't say **fastly** either. You could say **ran** instead of **rans** in the first sentence, but then **fastly** would still destroy the sentence.